# Excel - get x number of values from a list with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm working on a skewing and quality checking sheet right now in Excel on different tabs and I can't seem to make it work.

I'm using three columns for my skewing - Ref No, Assigned Person, Status (example: Done 10/24) - A1 to C1. To get values for the QC tab, I have a separate table in the same sheet (F2:H2) which says how many Ref Nos of each Assigned Person I should check. I need a formula to work on a value in a cell to say how many items from this person (Assigned Person column) finished on this date (Status) and it will automatically get x number of items from the list.

What if I would need to input a number in G2 - say I would only want to check 1 out of 2 reference numbers of assigned person1. If I input 1 or any number in G2 then it would automatically pull the same number of reference numbers in a different column. How can I do that?

I've attached screenshot of my Excel file.

[image: Updated Excel]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use COUNTIFS().

Comment: The ref #s would be unique. I would put a number in cell G2, say 2 and then it would pull out 2 reference numbers from the same assigned person and with the same status/date also. It has 2-3 conditions and I'm not sure how to properly create the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are wanting now. There is probably a better way of going about this, but I dont know it. So here is my complex set up.

I had to do this in multiple stages. This uses randarray so I would suggest changing formulas to manual calculation, and after hitting calculate copy and values paste the numbers so they do not change on you.

Also might add steps 1 and 2 on their own sheet and then hide it.

Stage 1:
[Image of first formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4zqi.jpg)
=SORTBY(UNIQUE(FILTER($A:$A,($B:$B=$H$1)*($C:$C=$E$2))),RANDARRAY(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A:$A,($B:$B=$H$1)*($C:$C=$E$2))))))

This will make a list of all the unique Ref# for Person 1 and marked Done 10/23. I know all the ref# are unique its just the way I know to get the list. The sortby, randarray will randomize the ref#s.

Step2: [Image of second formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13rX.jpg)
=IF($F$3>I1,"",I1)

Add a number column two columns to the left of the array. Number 1 through however large your file is.
Adding the if formula to the right of this column will give us a filter criteria to work with in step 3. So if you need 13 Ref#s this will add a 13 from the first row in array down to row 13.

Step3: [Image of third formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwaY8.jpg)
=UNIQUE(FILTER(H3:H9,($G$3:$G$9=$I$1)))

Based on the number you enter this formula will only return the ref#s with criteria to the left. So in the image I have it set to need 6, so I only get the first 6 numbers. But, if you need more ref# than there are marked you will get a 0 at the end of the array. If there are no ref# it returns the error. Just add an Iferror statement.

If you need both 10/23 and 10/24 to be in the same column just change the filter criteria in step one.

I assume you need the random reference number to do quality control checks, but I could still not be understanding what you are needing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This really worked and solved a problem I've been trying to solve for about a week now. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: No problem! I had a fun time trying to figure this one out. I learned a couple different formulas I wouldn't have with the work I do for my day job. So thank you for the question haha.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly I you can use the formulas below. If not, maybe you can adjust it to fit your desired result.

I have listed the formulas as text below the illustration.

[image: Proposal]

```
=COUNTIFS($C$4:$C$11,F$3,$B$4:$B$11,$E4)

=UNIQUE(IF((B3:$B$10=$I3)*($C$3:$C$10=J$2),$A$3:$A$10,""))

=OFFSET(G9#,0,0,$J$3,1)
```

Comment: The OFFSET function did wonders!!! I combined some of the formula given by LizbethEll and added the OFFSET. Thank you so much! You saved me!!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try =countifs(B:B,F2,C:C,$G$1) then drag down for each person. Drag over to the Done 10/24 and update the $G$1 reference to $H$1 reference.

The B:B is based on the column count of example, just make that and the C column reference the one on your sheet.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I would need to input a number in G2 say I would only want to check 1 out of 2 reference numbers of assigned person1. If I input 1 or any number in G2 then it would automatically pull the same number of reference numbers in a different column. How can I do that?

Comment: I am sorry, I am lost on what you are needing. You want to be able to enter ref# 4874 and it tell you when the person finished? Or, does your file have more than one entry for the same reference and need to have it check how many of that reference was completed on 10/23?

Comment: The ref #s would be unique. I would put a number in cell G2, say 2 and then it would pull out 2 reference numbers from the same assigned person and with the same status/date also. It has 2-3 conditions and I'm not sure how to properly create the formula